# How to open a file with float variables?

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to Python and to programming as well. 
I'm trying to read a file with decimal data in two rows (x and y) and get this error:' could not convert string to float: '#' '. How can I resolve this?

```
with open('file.txt','r') as csvfile:

...     plots=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

...     for row in plots:

...             x.append(int(float(row[0])))

...             y.append(int(float(row[1])))

...
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 4, in
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#'

EDIT: the upper part is solved (thanks for quick responses people!). The problem was that the file had a header line, which I deleted. Ofcourse, it is possible to start opening the file from 2nd. Also the file had two spaces instead of one between the columns, so I replaced the characters with notepad, since Python only allows one character long delimitors.

Now I'm trying to plot it and I get another error 'x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes'. What's the underlying mistake in the code? 
Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x=[]
y=[]

with open('file.txt','r') as csvfile:
...     plots=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
...     for row in plots:
...             x.append(int(float(row[0])))
...             y.append(int(float(row[1])))
...

plt.plot(x,y, label='spectra')
```

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (218605,) and (218604,)

The file has 200 000 lines, first 5 are:

```
4066.46745678 0.794766
4066.49045678 0.979478
4066.51345678 0.837846
4066.53645678 0.935674
4066.55945678 0.91354
```

Comment: Why are u first converting it to Float, then to int? Anyhow this will probably be a "," vs "." notation I guess, could you post the first lines (especially the one with the error)?

Comment: For csv files I recommend using `pandas`, if possible

Comment: Please show us how your file.txt looks line

Comment: One of the lines in your file begins with `#`. That can't be converted to a float. If your CSV file contains a header line or comment lines, you need to skip over them.

Comment: You could also just put `try/except` around the code that processes each line. If it gets an error, you skip that line.

Comment: **decimal data in two rows** Did you mean to say two *columns*?

Comment: I tried your example on a CSV containing `2.6 5` and it worked fine. I can only assume your file is malformed with respect to your expectations. It probably contains a `#` somewhere, and `float()` doesn't know how to handle that.

Comment: Thank you Barmar and Syncrossus # was the issue

Comment: And now I'm trying to plot the opened data, but I get an error 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes'. Updated the main thread, maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: What seems to be going on here is that `x` has one more entry than `y`. However, I don't really see how that's possible if the code you use is truly what you've written, since you never add anything to `x` without adding anything to `y`. Are you certain you're not using a `try/except` block that's preventing the script from terminating at a malformed row? Try `print(len(x))` and `print(len(y))` and report back.
On an unrelated note, I doubt that you want to cast your elements to `int`.

Comment: Solved it by rewriting the whole code. @Syncrossus you are right that x had one more value than y but in the file the numbers of values for x and y are equal so it was some other problem, not the file and not the code itself. Again, thanks for the help